# NullPointerException when calling Graphics.drawImage

Tags: java, image, graphics, nullpointerexception, fullscreen

I am getting a NullPointerException running my java code.

Both lines in this method are getting the error:

```
    public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 50, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(a.getImage(), 0, 0, 50, 0, null);
}
```

bg is declared like so:

```
 bg = new ImageIcon("D:\\Eclipse\\Workspace\\Game\\src\\GameTest1\\back.png").getImage();
```

a is this:

```
 private Animations a;
```

code:

```
package GameTest1;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Animations {

    private ArrayList scenes;
    private int sceneIndex;
    private long movieTime;
    private long totalTime;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Animations(){
        scenes = new ArrayList();
        totalTime = 0;
        start();
    }
    //adds screen to array list and adds time to things
    public synchronized void addScene(Image i, long t){ 
        totalTime += t;
        scenes.add(new OneScene(i, totalTime) );
    }
    //start animation from beginning
    public synchronized void start(){
        movieTime = 0;
        sceneIndex = 0;
    }
    //change scenes
    public synchronized void update(long timePassed){
        if(scenes.size() > 1){
            movieTime += timePassed;
            if(movieTime >= totalTime){
                movieTime = 0;
                sceneIndex = 0;
            }
            while(movieTime > getScene(sceneIndex).endTime){
                sceneIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
    //get current scene(image)
    public synchronized Image getImage(){
        if(scenes.size() == 0){
            return null;
        }else{
            return getScene(sceneIndex).pic;
        }
    }
    //get scene
    private OneScene getScene(int x){
        return (OneScene)scenes.get(x);
    }
    /////////////PRIVATE CLASSCEPTION///////////////
    private class OneScene{
    Image pic;
    long endTime;

    public OneScene(Image pic, long endTime){
        this.pic = pic;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

}
}
```

I know what a nullPointerException is, so please do not link me to a post describing what one is. My problem is I can't see what is causing the error.

Comment: Where's the stacktrace? And what is `a`?

Comment: `"I know what a nullPointerException is, so please do not link me to a post describing what one is."` -- If you know what a NPE is, then you should know already how to debug it. Have you tested to see just what is null? The key may be the Graphics object  -- how are you getting it?

Comment: @JustinJasmann  private Animations a; and the Animations class is now in the post

Comment: You're posting a lot of code, but none relevant to your problem. Again, how are you calling draw, where are you getting the Graphics object? Again, have you tested to see just what is null? Please let's avoid having this question closed for insufficient information.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Justin asked for the class, I'm calling draw with the CLASSNAME.run() at the top of my main class, and what do you mean by"where am I getting the Graphics object"

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> Both lines in this method are getting the error:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 50, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(a.getImage(), 0, 0, 50, 0, null);
}
```

This very clearly means that the `Graphics` object that you are passing to the `draw()` method, is null. Check the line of code that is calling `draw()`, and see why the `Graphics` object you are passing to it is null.

You should really read the answers to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) this question will inevitably be marked as a duplicate of. You have not yet learned how to debug a NPE.

Comment: Great minds think alike. 1+

Comment: I know I haven't found out how to debug a NPE... that's why I'm asking here. Also, I did say that I knew what a NPE was, but I didn't know what was causing it.

Comment: @user3532547 What causes an NPE? Erm calling a method on a null pointer.....

Answer (score 2):

You are calling:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 50, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(a.getImage(), 0, 0, 50, 0, null);
}
```

And getting a NullPointerException. First you must find the line throwing the NPE, and then test to see what is null. For example if it is the first line of the method:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    System.out.println("is g null? " + (g == null));
    System.out.println("is bg null? " + (bg == null));
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 50, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(a.getImage(), 0, 0, 50, 0, null);
}
```

Then if g is null, look back at where draw is called and see how you get the Graphics object.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> Okay, found where I'm calling draw: Graphics2D g = screen.getGraphics(); draw(g);

What is screen? If it's a component, then you're trying to get the Graphics out of it before it has been rendered, and it will be null. That's not how you use Graphics anyway. You should instead be drawing in the paintComponent method of a JPanel or JComponent override as per the [Swing painting tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Okay, found where I'm calling draw:   Graphics2D g = screen.getGraphics();
      
      draw(g);

Comment: @user3532547: finally. Please see edit.

Comment: screen is this class: http://pastebin.com/nTZxcQUg

Comment: @user3532547: so your getGraphics() method returns null if `vc.getFullScreenWindow()` returns null. Now, why is getFullScreenWindow() null and is this the behavior you expect? Why or why not?